# Taking microphone input as a json array

Tags: android, input, microphone

I am new in android.Currently i got one project.In that one i need to take the data from 
phone microphone input and also i need to take the values from that input.Is it possible to convert the microphone input into JSON format.Please give me one suggestion for this problem.

Comment: http://forums.reflector.net/questions/4011/sending-videoaudio-file-from-android-application-t.html

Comment: PCM samples are just numbers, so you can put them in a `JSONObject` the same way you would with any other numbers. It doesn't sound like a particularly efficient way of storing the data, however.

Comment: @Michael.How i take the datas from microphone input